# Why removeObserver causes objc_msgSend SIGSEGV in viewWillDisappear in this code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

First of all, it is a crash that I can not reproduce so I can not debug in Xcode. So I'm trying to reason it.

Stack trace:

```
Exception Type:  SIGSEGV
Exception Codes: SEGV_ACCERR at 0xc
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                      0x3a816b26 objc_msgSend + 5
1   Voodo 2                              0x000d8933 -[TagListViewController viewWillDisappear:] (TagListViewController.m:107)
2   UIKit                                0x32b68169 -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 472
3   UIKit                                0x32bc602b -[UIViewController viewWillMoveToWindow:] + 290
4   UIKit                                0x32b4be89 -[UIView _willMoveToWindow:] + 468
5   UIKit                                0x32b6e4df -[UIScrollView _willMoveToWindow:] + 122
6   UIKit                                0x32b4c7b5 __85-[UIView(Hierarchy) _makeSubtreePerformSelector:withObject:withObject:copySublayers:]_block_invoke + 77
7   UIKit                                0x32b4c6e5 -[UIView _makeSubtreePerformSelector:withObject:withObject:copySublayers:] + 376
8   UIKit                                0x32b4c7d5 __85-[UIView(Hierarchy) _makeSubtreePerformSelector:withObject:withObject:copySublayers:]_block_invoke + 109
9   UIKit                                0x32b4c6e5 -[UIView _makeSubtreePerformSelector:withObject:withObject:copySublayers:] + 376
10  UIKit                                0x32b4c7d5 __85-[UIView(Hierarchy) _makeSubtreePerformSelector:withObject:withObject:copySublayers:]_block_invoke + 109
11  UIKit                                0x32b4c6e5 -[UIView _makeSubtreePerformSelector:withObject:withObject:copySublayers:] + 376
12  UIKit                                0x32b4c7d5 __85-[UIView(Hierarchy) _makeSubtreePerformSelector:withObject:withObject:copySublayers:]_block_invoke + 109
13  UIKit                                0x32b4c6e5 -[UIView _makeSubtreePerformSelector:withObject:withObject:copySublayers:] + 376
14  UIKit                                0x32de333b __UIViewWillBeRemovedFromSuperview + 379
15  UIKit                                0x32b4badd -[UIView removeFromSuperview] + 56
16  UIKit                                0x32b4e407 -[UIView dealloc] + 366
17  UIKit                                0x32d3c0f1 -[UIWindow dealloc] + 824
18  libobjc.A.dylib                      0x3a818007 (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 359
19  CoreFoundation                       0x3030e981 _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 16
20  UIKit                                0x32b4624d _wrapRunLoopWithAutoreleasePoolHandler + 37
21  CoreFoundation                       0x303a61cd __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 21
22  CoreFoundation                       0x303a3b71 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 285
23  CoreFoundation                       0x303a3eb3 __CFRunLoopRun + 731
24  CoreFoundation                       0x3030ec27 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 522
25  CoreFoundation                       0x3030ea0b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
26  GraphicsServices                     0x35035283 GSEventRunModal + 138
27  UIKit                                0x32bb2049 UIApplicationMain + 1136
28  Voodo 2                              0x000c87df main (main.m:14)
29  libdyld.dylib                        0x3ad23ab7 start + 3
```

The code is very simple and using `ARC`:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [self refresh];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(refresh) name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object:self.managedObjectContext];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(refresh) object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object:self.managedObjectContext];
}

- (void)refresh {
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    // Refresh every 60s.
    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(refresh) object:nil];
    [self performSelector:@selector(refresh) withObject:nil afterDelay:60];
}
```

The crash occurs at the last line.

The only possible cause I can think of is that the `cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:selector:object:` call releases the last reference to `self` so `self` is dangling at the last line. However, I can not find any possible path for this situation to happen.

Comment: How refresh method is being implemented?

Comment: @ldindu I just added refresh method in the question.

Comment: Why are you calling refresh inside refresh method twice, I couldn't understand the logic here?

Comment: refresh method doesn't make sense to me here when view is disappear, how come it will be refresh every 60s as by then self will be deallocated.

Comment: What is the crash reason? Exception? Segmentation fault?

Comment: What happens if you comment the cancelpreviousrequest line from the viewwilldisappear?

Comment: @Hackmodford please notice that it is a crash that I can not reproduce. So it makes no other difference than introducing a logic bug to me to comment out the call.

Comment: Can you please show where you registered the notification center's observer?

Comment: @nomannasim `viewDidAppear:`. I added it in the question.